# How to format mytext file?

Tags: sql, mysql, load-data-infile

I have to load set of questions to MYSQL database table.But the table format is like below
QNO Questions Option a Option b Option c Option d Rightanswer... but my textfile which i need to load in database using LOADINFILE command is in different format. How can i match my textfile format to my table format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-map the columns to import in LOAD DATA INFILE.

Check the [manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Example:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.csv'
INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1, field2, field3);
```

I like using a graphical front-end like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com) to point-and-click the desired fields, and copy the generated SQL from there.

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon your table format, but if there is any complex preprocessing then it's probably a good idea to do it outside of mysql. It's probably a lot easier.